# How to add transparency to a html5 canvas

Tags: html5-canvas

So i was messing aroung with html5 canvas properties to create a graph for my statistics. I finally managed to turn those straight lines into smooth graphlike mountains but after i replaced **lineTo** with **quadraticCurveTo** the fillStyle of the graph changed form transparent rgba to a solid color.

Image of the graph
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xoRmq.png)

As you can see you can't exactly see the graph behind.

What i've tried(thats what i found googleing this issue):

```
ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 148, 133, 0.5)';
ctx.globalAlpha = 0.5;
```

Maybe you guys have solutions for me?

I also saw something about **fillRect** but i'm not exactly sure how to use fillrect on graphlike shape.

The end result coulb be something like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RZQ2x.png)

Answer (score 0):

I added a stroke to the graph and now it's exactly how i want it to be. Silly solution but i couldn't think of it at first.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fDEvh.png)